# SELECT and INSERT in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Can you help me please? I wrote this code and I get an error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword SELECT

Here is my code

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spSetCommand
    @Client_id INT,
    @BcNumber INT,
    @ArticleId INT,
    @EntryNumber DECIMAL
AS
    DECLARE @CommandId INT 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO commands(client_id, bc_number, date_command) 
    VALUES (@Client_id, @BcNumber, GETDATE());

    SET @CommandId = SELECT command_id 
                     FROM commands 
                     WHERE bc_number = @BcNumber;

    INSERT INTO entries(command_id, article_id, entry_number)  
    VALUES (@CommandId, @ArticleId, @EntryNumber);
END
```

Can someone help find the issue?

Comment: I've never seen a DECLARE before  BEGIN.  Not sure if that might be your issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
-- need to have brackets
set @CommandId = (SELECT command_id FROM commands WHERE bc_number = @BcNumber);
```

if there are multiple results from the query, this will fail, an error will come.

you can also use this:

```
SELECT @CommandID = command_id 
FROM commands
WHERE bc_number = @BcNumber
```

In case of multiple results, this will give you the last value (which may/may not be your logical thing)

Comment: @Rakotoarisoa try this one. i hope this will work for you

Comment: Thanks, it works. And I made a mistake to put the declare outside of the begin

Answer (score 0):

In SQL SELECT `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` Return Recent add record Identity Key in your case `command_id`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spSetCommand
        @Client_id INT,
        @BcNumber INT,
        @ArticleId INT,
        @EntryNumber DECIMAL
    AS
        DECLARE @CommandId INT 
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO commands(client_id, bc_number, date_command) 
        VALUES (@Client_id, @BcNumber, GETDATE());
SET @CommandId = SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
INSERT INTO entries(command_id, article_id, entry_number)  
        VALUES (@CommandId, @ArticleId, @EntryNumber);
    END
```

There is an error in the below line code:

```
SET @CommandId = SELECT command_id 
                     FROM commands 
                     WHERE bc_number = @BcNumber;
```

if there are multiples records exists `WHERE bc_number = @BcNumber` then this will generate an error other wise working fine.

Atrenate way is below:

```
SELECT @CommandId =command_id  commands WHERE bc_number = @BcNumber;
```

but the most appropriate way is to get recent added record in current table by current instant you can use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` SQL function

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @CommandId = SELECT command_id 
FROM commands 
WHERE bc_number = @BcNumber;
```

Instead try

```
SELECT @CommandId = top 1 command_id 
FROM commands 
WHERE bc_number = @BcNumber order by command_id desc;
```

I use set @foo = some int like 4; and select @foo = some query;